# PCA:how eigenvectors and eigen values work

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

**Scene:** currently I am working on image classification project . I have used HOG as image feature. dimension of hog feature vector was too large to feed neural net.so I decided to preprocess it with PCA to reduce its dimension.

**what i got:** I didn't knew about PCA.. then I searched for tutorial regarding that .While learning about PCA I faced Eigen values and Eigen vectors..what I understood was
let x->n-dimensional random vector(feature vector fed  for PCA) A->nxn matrix and l=(Scalar)scale factor.. then if transformation matrix A is chosen so that it satisfy following equation

**Ax=lx**

then x is called eigenvector and l is called Eigen values corresponding to A.
now with characteristic polynomial equation we estimate different values of l then for each l we estimate Eigen vector

**question:**

*1.i am confusing with random vector as feature vector which we need to reduce and matrix A containing coefficients of linear combination formed...I am I right or not.I mean x is transformed to lx then transformation matrix A should be estimated for given l but NO! A is given already.*

*2.If vector x is feature vector which we already have.then why we say that for each l(Eigen value) we calculate x(Eigen vector)*

*3.After looking at above facts It was confusing that if A is given and x is unknown then are we considering the feature vector actually.if yes is it A or x where it i.we are estimating Eigen values and vectors but wherer are we 
considering the feature vector we want to process*

*I am very confused of what is given and what we are calculating please help!*

Comment: Have you tried looking at those lines to see why the compiler is lost? Have you tried searching what is the [C2010 error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64sxk83h.aspx) ?

Comment: I watched those lines...A macro named as (format.....) is undefined in gmessage.h though gmacro.h is already included but still gives same error.I also watched for same macro i. 2.4 version of gtk .same thing but it worked fine there......

Comment: This is code in GLib that triggers the error, not GTK+. You didn't say which version of GLib you're linking to, sonor which version of GTK+ you're trying to build. So we can't check the code to see the specific lines that trigger the errors.

Comment: @liberforce well I saw the code, and point where error generated..But I must tell you I downloaded GTK +3.0 which still contains Glib 2.0 version which I linked with visual studio.Also error is generated by Glib.. Neither  my code nor gtk+ supplements..

Comment: The point is YOU saw the error and the code, but WE can't.

Comment: @liberforce shall i check the dlls....maybe dlls of 2.0 merging with 3.0....or the libraries or headers...

Comment: How did you linked @liberforce please share that also..

Comment: I can't try to help you if you don't answer the basic questions I already asked: which exact version of GTK+ and GLib are you trying to build? Where did you download them?

Comment: Well I am not building gtk... I have downloaded prebuild binary for windows from a website which is gtk 3.0 plus inside which i found glib 2.0 version and gtk 3.0 vwr headers and libs

Comment: GLib 2.0 was released in 2002, and GTK+ 3.0 in 2011. I very much doubt this is what you use. The naming scheme is x.y.z with x = major, y = minor, z = micro. We need at least x.y. And please give precise information. "from a website" is less than useful.

Comment: Sure why not. I downloaded binaries from [here](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/20)

Comment: Thanks. So instead of saying you're using GTK+ 3.0, you should have said that you use GTK+ 3.6.1. Those binaries are out of date, unmaintained by their author, and providing GTK+ bundles is no more supported by the GTK+ project. The supported way is through MSYS2, but you won't be able to use Visual Studio then. Some people do it though, so your best chance is to ask on the GTK+ IRC channel.

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry for my childish mistake.But i really dont want to lose msvs so where should i go?

Comment: Or do you have a better ui library for c++ in mind rather than this which is capable of making cool ui and i can also use css and xml with